# Simple JavaScript Game

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to make a basic Space Invaders clone in ECMAScript/HTML5/CSS3 with the shortest and simplest code possible. I have begun implementing the controls, but they won't work. Here is the code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onkeydown="javascript:move()" onkeyup=""></body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width=800 height=800></canvas>

<script>

var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 40, 40);
}
img.src = "run0.png";


function leftArrowPressed() {
  img.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
  img.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
}
function move(evt) {
  var code = window.event.keyCode;
  switch (code) {
    case 37:
      leftArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 39:
      rightArrowPressed();
      break;
  }
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.event` only exists during an event, you can't just look it up whenever. You will need to attach event listeners (and probably passing the event straight into them would be better than looking at `window.event`)

Comment: `move()` is not triggered by the event you are looking for. Where is `element` coming from?

Comment: ok, I've made some changes, but I'm not sure how to properly make/link the event listener for the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling your `keydown` event in the markdown of your `<body>` tag. You can listen to events programatically with JavaScript, or continue as you were doing by adding the `move()` method to your `onkeydown` attribute like so:

```js
function leftArrowPressed() {
  console.log('move left');
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
  console.log('move right');
}

function move(evt) {
  var code = window.event.keyCode;
  switch (code) {
    case 37:
      leftArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 39:
      rightArrowPressed();
      break;
  }
};
```

```html
<body onkeydown="javascript:move()" onkeyup=""></body>
```

In order for the above to work (inside an iframe), it must first be focused. So click the white space where the demo opens up before testing.

It should be noted that interfacing the keyboard in browsers has been historically a bit of a headache. Your best bet is to delegate the task to a good library.

I have found the [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) library to be pretty extensive.

Comment: Thanks, I will in a professional application, but I want to make this pure JS/HTML5/CSS3, without using ids for images.

Comment: @Jona A Javascript library is not another language. It is still pure JavaScript, but it has been written for a specific purpose in order to make a particular thing easier to understand. Either way, I have given you the 'pure Javascript' version, before recommending the library. Also, I'm not sure why 'ids for images' has anything to do with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a mainloop so just set some flags and attach your key events to the document, no need to worry about focus. Ship will move as long as the key is held down. Fire button will need to have a reload flag and a timer to control the repeat rate. Fire reloads at key up or if `reloadTime === 0.` When firing set `reload` to `true` and `reloadTime` to repeat rate (in frames). In the key event reload on key up by setting `reload = false` .

That is about as simple as you can make it.

```
var framesPerSecond = 30;
var shipX = 0; // ship pos
var leftKeyDown = false;  // key down flags
var rightKeyDown = false;
var fireKeyDown = false;
var reloadTime = 0;  // fire key needs a timer a timer/counter inbuilt keyboard repeat will take over and mess with your repeat rate.
var reload = false; // dont want the keyboard repeat to trigger shots at the wrong time so
                    // flag that you need to reload when the next key up
                    // arrives.
function mainLoop(){
    if(leftKeyDown){ // move left if left key down
        shipX -= 1;
    }
    if(rightKeyDown){ // move right if right key down
        shipX += 1;
    }
    if(fireKeyDown && !reload){ //fire is not needing to reload and fire key down
        //log("FIRE"); // sends a bullet
        reload = true; // need to reload
        reloadTime = 10; // number of frames till reload.
    }
    if(reload && reloadTime > 0){ // if needing to reload
        reloadTime -= 1;  // count down frames 
        if(reloadTime === 0){ // until time to reload.
            reload = false;   // then reload.
        }
    }
    ....
    // game stuff.
    ...

    // can use requestAnimationFrame if you use canvas
    // requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // 60 frames a second
    // or because you are doing it in HTML
    setTimeout(mainLoop,1000 / framesPerSecond);

}

function keyEvent(event){ // handle ky up and downs.
    var state = false;  // assume up
    if(event.type === "keydown"){ // if down
        state = true;  // set as down
    }
    if(event.keyCode === 37){ // left key
        leftKeyDown = state;  // set key state
    }else
    if(event.keyCode === 39){ // right key
        rightKeyDown = state; // set key sate
    }else
    if(event.keyCode === 32){ // space
        fireKeyDown = state;  
        if(!state && reload){ // reload if needed and key up
            reload = false;
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyEvent);
```